# Google Cloud Fedora ssh connection problem

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, ssh, virtual-machine, fedora

I was created vm fedora 33 on google cloud but i can't connection with ssh. Actualy i can connect debian vm's but can't only fedora vm's.

Ssh error is

`Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).`

also my public key type is rsa.

Comment: Always good to read the changes when installing a new system https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/StrongCryptoSettings2

Comment: Have you tried verbose mode for your ssh connection ? `-vvv` flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Generate key pair: `ssh-keygen -t ed25519`
2. Copy public key to instance metadata - [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#instance-only).
3. Restart the instance.
4. Connect using new key: `ssh -i <KEY_FILE> core@<INSTANCE_PUBLIC_IP>`

You can find more information [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/jhxbdh/no_ssh_public_key_auth_after_upgrade_to_fedora_33/).

Comment: It's work for me. I was try this solution before but i am not try for core user. Thanks for answer.