# Problem with Fedora SSH connection on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, virtual-machine, gcloud, fedora

I am having problem with connecting to my new instance directly from the browser. This is literally a new instance of Fedora OS so I have not configured anything. It doesn't work out of the box.

I have other servers with OS like Debian 10 (Buster) and they seem to work fine when connecting through SSH.

**Here are the server specs that I am using for the VM:**

```
Machine type: e2-medium (2 vCPUs, 4 GB memory)
CPU platform: Intel Broadwell
Zone: us-central1-a
OS Image: fedora-coreos-34-20210904-3-0-gcp-x86-64
Disk Size: 30GB
Disk Type: SSD
```

**Here are the logs from the serial port:** ([Link to entire log from serial port](https://0bin.net/paste/JmDBORRu#DA5zS3KBtgmKqkJRFYTlEp4jzJuED7dx6nZ9s10XPyv))

```
[  545.747496] audit: type=2404 audit(1633250527.525:300): pid=1892 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=destroy kind=server fp=SHA256:80:d3:1d:38:a5:96:e3:02:50:e1:55:11:ec:61:1b:65:89:6e:08:ad:4d:50:09:82:2d:a6:cb:c8:fa:35:6c:c7 direction=? spid=1893 suid=74  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[  545.780996] audit: type=1109 audit(1633250527.525:301): pid=1892 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:bad_ident grantors=? acct="?" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=74.125.73.141 addr=74.125.73.141 terminal=ssh res=failed'
[  545.806261] audit: type=2404 audit(1633250527.526:302): pid=1892 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=destroy kind=server fp=SHA256:80:d3:1d:38:a5:96:e3:02:50:e1:55:11:ec:61:1b:65:89:6e:08:ad:4d:50:09:82:2d:a6:cb:c8:fa:35:6c:c7 direction=? spid=1892 suid=0  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[  545.839942] audit: type=1112 audit(1633250527.526:303): pid=1892 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=login acct="(unknown)" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=74.125.73.141 terminal=ssh res=failed'
[  564.968011] audit: type=2404 audit(1633250546.749:304): pid=1895 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=destroy kind=server fp=SHA256:80:d3:1d:38:a5:96:e3:02:50:e1:55:11:ec:61:1b:65:89:6e:08:ad:4d:50:09:82:2d:a6:cb:c8:fa:35:6c:c7 direction=? spid=1895 suid=0  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[  565.344660] audit: type=2407 audit(1633250547.122:305): pid=1894 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=start direction=from-server cipher=aes128-ctr ksize=128 mac=hmac-sha2-256 pfs=diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 spid=1895 suid=74 rport=32883 laddr=10.128.15.203 lport=22  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=74.125.17.13 terminal=? res=success'
[  565.382463] audit: type=2407 audit(1633250547.122:306): pid=1894 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=start direction=from-client cipher=aes128-ctr ksize=128 mac=hmac-sha2-256 pfs=diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 spid=1895 suid=74 rport=32883 laddr=10.128.15.203 lport=22  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=74.125.17.13 terminal=? res=success'
[  566.988544] audit: type=2404 audit(1633250548.769:307): pid=1894 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=destroy kind=session fp=? direction=both spid=1895 suid=74 rport=32883 laddr=10.128.15.203 lport=22  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=74.125.17.13 terminal=? res=success'
[  567.021621] audit: type=2404 audit(1633250548.800:308): pid=1894 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=destroy kind=server fp=SHA256:80:d3:1d:38:a5:96:e3:02:50:e1:55:11:ec:61:1b:65:89:6e:08:ad:4d:50:09:82:2d:a6:cb:c8:fa:35:6c:c7 direction=? spid=1895 suid=74  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[  567.057403] audit: type=1109 audit(1633250548.800:309): pid=1894 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:bad_ident grantors=? acct="?" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=74.125.17.13 addr=74.125.17.13 terminal=ssh res=failed'
[  567.082647] audit: type=2404 audit(1633250548.800:310): pid=1894 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=destroy kind=server fp=SHA256:80:d3:1d:38:a5:96:e3:02:50:e1:55:11:ec:61:1b:65:89:6e:08:ad:4d:50:09:82:2d:a6:cb:c8:fa:35:6c:c7 direction=? spid=1894 suid=0  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[  567.116466] audit: type=1112 audit(1633250548.801:311): pid=1894 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=login acct="(unknown)" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=74.125.17.13 terminal=ssh res=failed'
```

**Here's what I have tried so far:**

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67003527/google-cloud-fedora-ssh-connection-problem), I tried to manually add SSH key to my instance meta data but that doesn't seem to work as well. When I try to connect through SSH, I get the following error:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

I have also tried to connect through Google's OS Login console and it still doesn't connect for some reason. Here's the console output for that:

```
gcloud beta compute ssh --zone "us-central1-a" "instance-1"  --project "XXX"
Warning: Permanently added 'compute.178891790600165087' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
XXX@123.456.789.123: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57498795/permission-denied-publickey-freebsd-in-google-computer-engine/57512037#57512037) to trboueshoot a 255 error

Comment: @danyL, thank you for your reply. Unfortunately that did not help as well. I have updated my post to include all of the logs from the serial port.

Comment: Researching about I found in the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#limitations) that "Fedora CoreOS images do not support OS Login" and to be able to manage instance access to VMs with this image you can follow the next [link](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora-coreos/producing-ign/). Please let me know if it useful for your case.

Comment: @Vicky, thank you! I figured adding public key to instance metadata by the username `core` seems to solve the issue. Any other username is rejected. I am not sure why this is happening.

Comment: I would like to ask you if you could put the solution as an answer and accept it to help the community to make easier for them to find the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Vicky, thank you for reminding me. I have submitted my answer. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding public key to instance metadata by the username `core` seems to solve the issue. Any other username is rejected.

1. Generate key pair: `ssh-keygen -t ed25519`
2. Copy public key to instance metadata - [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#instance-only).
3. Restart the instance.
4. Connect using new key: `ssh -i <KEY_FILE> core@<INSTANCE_PUBLIC_IP>`

More information about this issue can also be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/jhxbdh/no_ssh_public_key_auth_after_upgrade_to_fedora_33/).

Comment: I kept using my username and kept getting permission denied, when using fedora coreos username should be "core"